# Storing and mapping currency exchange rates

Tags: sql-server, types

I need to store on SQLServer 2008 R2 currency exchange rate data.

The application making use of this data is developed in C#. The column holding the currency exchange rate will be required to store conversions both ways-- meaning, I'd rather have a fixed precision but a variable scale.

What Data type should I choose on SQL Server that can be mapped to C# avoiding any data loss? I'm looking at MSDN supplied [mappings matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx#BehaviorMatrix) and I'm can't seem to find anything that I can safely handle.

- Float(53) could be a possibility, but
  floats are approximate values.
- Money are only accurate to the ten
  thousandth of the unit

I'm left with Decimal. However these offer fixed scales. And that's where I'm stumped:

If I'm required to store a number like `0.0104182` but also `123.673`, I've established a precision of 10 as my requirement. But how should I set a scale that can fully accommodate this precision?

Comment: I've never tried it, but could you use a bigint instead? You'd have to convert all the numbers (and ensure that you retain the same precision for all of them), but it might be a quick, easy, "lossless" way of storing and calculating values.

Comment: That would mean another field on the currency exchange rate table to inform the bigint of its scale. But it would solve my problem, for sure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For exchange rates I'd use decimal (19, 9) or so.

You have to allow for "telephone number" rates

Examples, at current rates 1 British Pound is

- 13,835.87699 Indonesian Rupiah
- 33,016.24786 Vietnamese Dong